# pthread synchronization on two consumers one producer

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a worker thread processing a queue of work items.

```
//producer
void push_into_queue(char *item) {
    pthread_mutex_lock (&queueMutex);
    if(workQueue.full) { // full }
    else{
        add_item_into_queue(item);
        pthread_cond_signal (&queueSignalPush);
    }   
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueMutex);
}
// consumer1
void* worker(void* arg) {
    while(true) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queueMutex);
        while(workQueue.empty)
            pthread_cond_wait(&queueSignalPush, &queueMutex);

        item = workQueue.front; // pop from queue
        add_item_into_list(item);

        // do I need another signal here for thread2?
        pthread_cond_signal(&queueSignalPop);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueMutex);
    }   
    return NULL;
}
pthread_create (&thread1, NULL, (void *) &worker, NULL);
```

Now I would like to have `thread2` consume the data inserted in `add_item_into_list()` but only if items have been added to the list. Note that the list is permanent and can't be emptied nor freed for the entire duration of the program.

So my question is: do I need another `pthread_cond_signal`?, if yes, where would this signal go? and how my other worker would look like (canonical form)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 possible ways of solving the problem:

a. Introduce another condition variable (e.g. `signalList`) for the list, so that `consumer2` thread would wait for events on it. In this case `consumer1` have to signal twice: once on `queueSignalPop` and once on `signalList`:

```
// consumer1
void* worker(void* arg) {
    while(true) {
        // ...
        pthread_cond_signal(&queueSignalPop);
        pthread_cond_signal(&signalList);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueMutex);
    }   
    return NULL;
}
```

b. Use existing condition `queueSignalPop` variable inside `consumer2` to wait for events, and use *broadcast* instead of signal inside `consumer1`. Broadcast means all the waiting threads on condition variable will wake up:

```
// consumer1
void* worker(void* arg) {
    while(true) {
        // ...
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&queueSignalPop);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueMutex);
    }   
    return NULL;
}
// consumer2
void* worker2(void* arg) {
    while(true) {
        while(list.empty)
            pthread_cond_wait(&queueSignalPop, &queueMutex);
        // ...
    }   
    return NULL;
}
```

I would propose to go for the first approach, since it better distinguish the purpose of each condition variable.